# Div width not working for me

Tags: css, html, styles

```
<div id="content" style ="background-color:#ffffff;" style="width:600px;">
```

with this it makes a div and makes the background white. However i streches along the whole width of the page. How can I make it to it only streches acrosss the size I put in?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `style` attribute twice.  That is invalid.  Put it there only once.

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:600px;">
```

Better yet, use CSS

```
<div id="content">

#content {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the div have rounded corners?

Comment: @bob that is a separate question, but yes with `border-radius`

Answer (score 0):

you have two `style` attributes which cause an error. use this:

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:600px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same attribute multiple times..

CSS rules can be separated by `;`

```
<div id="content" style ="background-color:#ffffff;width:600px;">
```